# System.Drawing.Size equivalent for console application

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

Is there a struct (like **System.Drawing.Size**), that has two integers?
I'm writing a C# console application and would like to use this struct, but apparently you cannot use `System.Drawing` in a console application.

I'm wondering if another such struct exists before writing my own.

Comment: Well, there's [`Tuple<int, int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx). (Note that this is a class, not a struct! It does not have value semantics.)

Comment: "it will not let me import System.Drawing" - you mean the namespace? Have you tried adding a reference to the *System.Drawing.dll* assembly?

Comment: How exactly have you tried to use `System.Drawing`, and what exactly happened?

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time. Create a new question for your "side note".

Comment: For your side note, you could use `out` parameters, but I would instead consider returning a struct.  This is usually the right thing to do, as it allows you to easily extend the struct in the future to hold more data members, while using `out` parameters would require you to modify the function's signature.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Ok, I'll remove it then. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper The System.Drawing reference trick worked perfectly, though the given answer is also good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a struct that has two integers you can just use a `Tuple`

```
var point = Tuple.Create( 0, 0);
int x = point.Item1;
int y = point.Item2;
```

That being said you should be able to add a reference to `System.Drawing.dll` in order to allow you to use `using System.Drawing;` in your Console application.

Answer (score 2):

Who says you cannot use `System.Drawing` in a console application.  I'm using it right now in a service that resizes images.  Just add the reference, and use `Size`.

Comment: Also may be important to consider whether `Point` or `Size` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I find code that uses tuples to be horribly unreadable. I think if something's worth doing, it's worth doing well.

In the case of a Point struct, you need to make it immutable (unlike Microsoft's amateur effort!) and implement value-style comparisons. Something like this:

```
public struct Point2D: IEquatable<Point2D>
{
    public Point2D(int x, int y)
    {
        _x = x;
        _y = y;
    }

    public int X
    {
        get { return _x; }
    }

    public int Y
    {
        get { return _y; }
    }

    public bool Equals(Point2D other)
    {
        return _x == other._x && _y == other._x;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _x.GetHashCode() ^ _y.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is Point2D))
        {
           return false;
        }

        return Equals((Point2D)obj);
    }

    public static bool operator==(Point2D point1, Point2D point2)
    {
        return point1.Equals(point2);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Point2D point1, Point2D point2)
    {
        return !point1.Equals(point2);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("({0}, {1})", _x, _y);
    }

    private readonly int _x;
    private readonly int _y;
}
```

Comment: I agree.  To support tuples the language needs destructuring assignment, and even then the lack of documentation associated with the items of the particular tuple - which either have no name or a completely generic "ItemN" name - means that Tuple<int,int> is problematic:  is it width, height or height, width?  What C# could really use is a (set of) language constructs for being able to quickly create immutable structs, like the one you wrote here, except with fewer lines to write and less opportunity to miss something.